# How to solve $y' + xy^2 = 2xy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve $y' + xy^2 = 2xy$

I'm using the rule of Linear differential equations:

[image]

$a(x) = -2x , b(x) = xy^2 , A(x) = -x^2$

I've got to $y = -2 + c$ which isn't true according to the answers in my book.

The answer is :$(Ce^{-x^2} - 1)y = 2$

Comment: Both a (x) and b (x) should only be functions of x.

Comment: @Rohan This is what I thought too, how can I approach this then? I try homogen too which doesn't work, and sepertable seems to not work also

Comment: Why do you think 'separable' does not work here? See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm using the rule of Linear differential equations:

But the equation *isn't linear* (because of the $y^2$). However, it is *separable*:
$$y'+xy^2=2xy \iff y' = -x\left(y^2-2y\right)\iff \frac{y'}{y^2-2y} = -x$$

Does that help? You can now integrate both sides.

Note: it is also a *Bernoulli equation*, so you could also use the substitution $u=y^{-1}$.

Comment: Perfect. learned much from it, thank you! P.S. soon learning Bernoulli.

Comment: Alright, you're welcome! You can do it again with Bernoulli later and check if it gives you the same solution :).

Answer (score 2):

$$y' -2xy=-xy^2 $$
$$\frac{y'}{y^2}-2\frac{x}{y}=-x$$
let $u=\frac{1}{y}$
$$u'=-\frac{y'}{y^2}$$
so
$$-u'-2xu=-x$$
$$u'+2xu=x$$
now you can solve it as a linear first order D.E